# GGPlot annotation gets pushed off page scale when combining multiple plots within grid.draw

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotations, grid, scale

I have 5 plots for 5 different groups. I want to indicate a statistically significant difference a specific time points. I used annotate() to place asterisks in individual plots above the time points. However, when I combine all the plots together to make one figure, the asterisks get pushed off the plots. It looks like it is a problem with the y scales not being fixed. I'm providing as much data as I feel comfortable with. The first bit of code is for one of the groups. The plots all look relatively similar for the 5 groups. The second bit is the data frame I am using to combine the plots. Pictures attached of one plot by itself, then all plots combined. There should be multiple asterisks on multiple plots

```
ggplot(data,aes(X,Y,group=Group,color=Group))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.major=element_line(color="white",size=.1))+
  theme(panel.grid.minor=element_line(color="white",size=.1))+
  geom_point(stat="summary")+
  geom_errorbar(stat="summary",fun.data=mean_se,width=0.25)+
  geom_line(stat="summary")+
  scale_color_manual(labels = c("C", "T"),values=c("black", "red"))+
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=2.5))+
  annotate("text", x=5, y=3, label= "*",size=10)

grid.newpage()

grid.draw(rbind(ggplotGrob(plotanimal1), 
            ggplotGrob(plotanimal2), 
            ggplotGrob(plotanimal3), 
            ggplotGrob(plotanimal4), 
            ggplotGrob(plotanimal5)))
```

[image: One Graph]

[image: All 5 graphs]

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this is an easy issue to fix with faceting. try `?ggplot::facet_wrap` to learn more. If you want more help than that, post some sample data with `dput`

Comment: Where would I put facet_wrap in the code above? In each individual graph or in the data frame?

Comment: again, we would need sample data to help with the code. Either post the data with dput or make up some fake data that has the same data structure as your data.

Comment: Another option would be to make the asterixes `geom_point` with the `aes` values set to the appropriate x-y values. Then ggplot will adjust the y axes automatically to fit the asterixes in. You can set `shape = 7` to get an asterix

Comment: Allan Cameron, that seems to work but it unfortunately (1) shape=7 is not an asterisk and (2) it modifies the legend and overlays a picture of the symbol on top of C and T. We're getting close though!

Comment: Shape =8 or shape = 42 seem to get good asterisk symbols. The problem is just that the asterisk covers up the legend symbols

Comment: Actually when I use shape = 42 the asterisk doesn't show up in the legend. You got it to work. Please submit your response as an answer so I can mark it as solved and you can get some points

Comment: Glad that worked out. I have posted an answer - thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the asterisks by using `geom_point` with `shape = 42`. That way, ggplot will automatically fix the y axis values itself. You need to set the aesthetics at the same values you would have with `annotate`. So instead of

```r
 annotate("text", x=5, y=3, label= "*",size=10)
```

You can do

```r
 geom_point(aes(x=5, y=3), shape = 42, size = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the package `patchwork` to organize the plots? It typically works better than grid.draw